# Does Matlab have builtin OCR library or toolkit?

Tags: matlab, ocr, tesseract, matlab-cvst

I need a pre-built (i.e. already trained) OCR library that recognizes easy characters (standard fonts like Arial, Times New Roman, Courier, etc).  Does Matlab have anything like that in one of its toolboxes?  Or do I have to use an external program like Tesseract (and interface using system calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with an official MATLAB OCR toolbox. However, you can find all sorts of gems in the MATLAB File Exchange, like [this OCR tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition-ocr). It's pretty neat.

Comment: Is it just a machine learning algorithm that would still need to be trained with my own character set?  Or has it already been trained for standard Ascii/Latin characters?

Comment: No, it has preconfigured templates for capital letters in the included `templates.mat`, but you can create your own templates as well (take a look at `create_template.m`).

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB R2014a there's a builtin ocr function in Computer Vision System Toolbox.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html