# How to recognize printed number in image processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have met a problem about printed number recognition, like recognizing 0~9 in the image and got result.

[image]

In the image if you have patient to visit, there are many numbers and I want to convert image inside one circle into its real number, like sub image "209" in left-top corner should output 209.

I have already splitted image successfully and now it could treat sub image "209" as three image  with image "2","0" and "9". But I am not sure what's the best feature for distinguishing them, (currently I use projection number in horizonal and vertical and use distince based on that), now accurate rate is not satisfied, could you give me some advices? Thanks.

By the way, background of this problem comes from a game called Weiqi in Chinese and GO may be more general, most popular in China, Korea and Japan. I'd like to instruct that if any one has interested in that.

Comment: since all numbers appearing in your image are of the same size, font and orientation (upright) why don't you just correlate them with pre-computed templates?

Comment: You could look into one of the open source OCR (Optical Character Recognition) APIs.

Comment: thanks @Shai, first reason is I can't suppose image size will be always same as maybe I will input a larger image in the future, second reason is count of number in every sub image may be different, like image "19" has two numbers and image "199" has three numbers, it's not easy to define its position. I am not sure, I will try your idea, thanks again

Comment: @trumpetlicks I build a project with MATLAB, is there any API there? I am not familiar with OCR, thanks.

Comment: You can correlate ([`normxcorr2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html)) with 0-9 template and check for possible multiple matches in each sub image.

Comment: @Shai, thanks a lot, how nice you are. I will try it.

Comment: Look at this Stack Overflow Answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309885/does-matlab-have-builtin-ocr-library-or-toolkit